# PHP - Funciones | Métodos de Instancia $var→func($args)→func2($args);

Tags: php

Me preguntaba como podría hacer este tipo de funciones, o más bien como crear un clase o lo que se requiera para poder ejecutar las funciones del siguiente modo:

```
$var->metodo1($args)->metodo2($args)->metodo3($args);
```

> Bajo lo que supongo del codigo de arriba, es que el resultado de **metodo1** es utilizado por **metodo2** y el resultado de éste es utilizado por **metodo3**.

No sé como se le llama a esa clase de organización, por eso hago la pregunta de éste modo. He visto codigo muy similar en *Laravel*.

No sé si estoy equivocado, por eso pregunto. Intenté buscar en Google pero no encontré nada.

Comment: Creo recordar que no es exactamente asi.   -> es una llamada a un metodo de un objeto por lo que en tu ejemplo metodo1 debe retornar un objeto que tenga un metodo2 y metodo2 debe retornar un objeto que tenga un metodo3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Las "flechas" hacen referencia a un método de instancia (las funciones que puede invocar un objeto cuando está instanciado), al aplicar una tras otra cada método invocado debería retornar un objeto, con un ejemplo quizás se entienda más:

```
class Foo() {

    public function devolverNumeroAlCuadrado($num) {
        return $num * $num;
    }

    public function otroMetodo($num) {
        echo "Cualquier cosa";
    }
}

$var= new Foo(); // Instancio el objeto

$var->devolverNumeroAlCuadrado(2)->otroMetodo(); // ERROR!
```

Arroja error ya que como `devolverNumeroAlCuadrado()` devuelve un número, al llamar a `otroMetodo()` le estamos diciendo algo como esto:

```
4->otroMetodo();
```

Y el número 4 no tiene ese método. Por ende, si queremos llamar a `otroMetodo()` lo que retornen los métodos anteriores va a tener que ser la misma instancia:

```
class Foo() {

    public function unMetodo() {
        // Hace algo
        return $this; // Retorna el objeto llamador
    }

    public function otroMetodo($num) {
        echo "Cualquier cosa";
    }
}

$obj1 = new Foo(); // Instancio el objeto

$obj1->unMetodo()->otroMetodo(); // AHORA SI!!!
```

Otro ejemplo usando dos clases distintas:

```
class Foo() {

    public function unMetodo() {
        // Hace algo
        return $this; // Retorna el objeto llamador
    }

    public function otroMetodo($num) {
        return new Bar();
    }
}

class Bar() {
    public function metodoSalvaje() {
        echo "Soy un Bar!";
    }
}

$obj1 = new Foo(); // Instancio el objeto

$obj1->unMetodo()->otroMetodo()->metodoSalvaje();
```

Espero haber sido claro y útil!

Saludos!

Comment: **También pueden llamarse a clases externas.**

Comment: En ese caso los valores de retorno deben ser instancias del método que se quiere llamar. Para no perderte te recomiendo ir almacenanfo los resultados en variables en vez de poner todo en una línea, así se puede debuguear y leer más rápido y fácil

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f75678997ef846cb0ffd40fadd6da2e720200d14 ^^

Comment: Jajajaja excelente! Lo entendiste!

Comment: Acordate de marcar como correcta a la respuesta si te solucionó el problema para dar por cerrada la pregunta! Saludos!

Comment: Agrega el código que te comenté para que la respuesta esté completa :)

Comment: Cuando llego a casa la completo (Y)

Answer (score 3):

Sólo para aportar otro punto de vista:

También se puede tener un encadenador de clases, el cual te permite llamar los métodos de esta forma:

```
$prueba->foo()->bar()->fou();
```

sin tener que modificar las clases `foo`,  `bar`, `fou`. En ese caso la instancia de la clase prueba se creará mediante la clase `Encadenador` de este modo:

```
$prueba = new Encadenador('Prueba');
```

---

#### `Ejemplo:`[`Ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/OLG62359)

```
<?php 

class Prueba 
{
    function foo(){ echo "FOO\n"; }
    function bar(){ echo "BAR\n"; }
    function fou(){ echo "FOU\n"; }
}



class Encadenador 
{
    private $instance = null;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $pars = func_get_args();
        $this->instance = is_object($obj=array_shift($pars))?$obj:new $obj($pars);
    }

    public function __call($name,$pars)
    {
        call_user_func_array([$this->instance,$name],$pars);
        return $this;
    }

}


$prueba = new Encadenador('Prueba');   
$prueba->foo()->bar()->fou();

?>
```

#### `Resultado:`

```
FOO
BAR
FOU
```

Comment: Wow.  Que sutil...

Comment: Una pregunta... Si en la clase *Prueba* hay una función que llama a otra clase funciona igualmente?

Comment: Claro que sí. Los demos están para eso, para probar. Si creas una clase `Prueba2` y la llamas desde un método de `Prueba`,llamado por ejemplo  `muyfou():`  también te funciona si haces esto: `$prueba->foo()->bar()->fou()->muyfou();` Lo puedes probar si quieres, usando el enlace del demo.

Answer (score 1):

que tal? Me parece que lo que vos querés hacer, es chainear métodos.
Esto es un patrón bastante utilizado, en el cual el retorno de cada método en la clase que quieras chainear, devolvés la instancia de la clase.
Por ejemplo:

```
class miClase {

   public function metodo1($var1) {
      echo "Este es el metodo 1 y recibió ".$var1;      
      return $this; // <-- aca esta la magia

   } 

   public function metodo2($var2) {
      echo "Este es el metodo 2 y recibió ".$var2;
      return $this; // <-- aca esta la magia
   } 
}
```

Luego, hacés:

```
$obj = new miClase();
$obj->metodo1("hola")->metodo2("mundo");
```

Como método 1 devuleve la instancia ($obj), se puede chainear automáticamente con metodo2. 
Es tan simple como eso.

Saludos!