# Como ejecutar varios metodos de una clase en una misma linea PHP

Tags: php, clase, método

Hola queria saber que estructura debe tener la clase para que una vez instanciada, se pueda ejecutar varios metodos en una sola linea, por ejemplo vi en varios CMS o proyectos esto:

```
$NombreClase = new NombreClase();
$NombreClase->crearTexto('algo')->convertirAMatusculas()->hacerOtraCosa();
```

Esto, como se hace? Que estructura tiene que tener la clase o que propiedades debe tener cada metodo?

Saludos

Comment: Hay varias respuestas [en esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/82500/29967) que proponen una solución para tu caso.

Answer (score 6):

La idea seria crear un método de instancia. Fijate este ejemplo cumple con lo que planteaste.

Siempre tene en cuenta lo que retornan las funciones.

```
class NombreClase {

    private $algo;

    public function crearTexto($algo) {
        $this->algo=$algo;
        return $this;
    }

    public function convertirAMayusculas() {
        $this->algo=strtolower($this->algo);
        return $this;
    }

    public function hacerOtraCosa(){
        return $this;
    }
}

$NombreClase = new NombreClase();
$NombreClase->crearTexto('algo')->convertirAMayusculas()->hacerOtraCosa();
```

Esto deberia funcionar.

Salu2.-

Comment: Pero si yo en una clase utilizo otras propiedades y no solamente el $this->algo, entonces como sabe cual retornar?

Comment: Mmmm... no entiendo lo que estas preguntando. Cualquier otro atributo  (vos lo llamas propiedad) dentro de una clase se accede como $this->atributo.

Answer (score 2):

Todos tus métodos de la clase `$NombreClase` deben finalizar con `return $this;`

Comment: Pero si yo en una clase utilizo otras propiedades y no solamente el $this->algo, entonces como sabe cual retornar?

Comment: Para propiedades de la clase usa métodos set y get, para otros métodos retorna `$this`. Cuando hagas el encadenamiento como aqui: `$NombreClase->crearTexto('algo')->convertirAMatusculas()->hacerOtraCosa();` si llamas a una clase set o get esta tendra siempre que ser la ultima, así: `$NombreClase->crearTexto('algo')->convertirAMatusculas()->hacerOtraCosa()->getAlgo();` debido a que al llamar a una de estas funciones, terminaria el encadenamiento.