# Llamar métodos de una clase iniciados dentro de otra clase como si fueran propios

Tags: php, poo

Tengo una clase con muchos métodos y quiero sacar algunos a otras clases para iniciar dentro de la misma clase, pero para evitar un recoding, quiero que se sigan llamando de la misma forma.

Por ejemplo, ahora estaría así:

```
class BigClass{

    public function a(){
        return "algo";
    }

    public function b(){
        return "nada";
    }
}
```

De esta forma puedo llamar los métodos así:

```
$BigClass = new BigClass();
$BigClass->a();
$BigClass->b();
```

Ahora lo que quiero es que parte de esto se inicie dentro como otra clase, por ejemplo:

```
class BigClass{

    __construct(){
        $this->SmallClass = new SmallClass();
    }

    public function a(){
        return "algo";
    }
}

class SmallClass{

    public function b(){
        return "nada";
    }
}
```

Esto podría usarlo así:

```
$BigClass = new BigClass();
$BigClass->a();
$BigClass->SmallClass->b();
```

Pero yo quiero seguir usándolo como antes para evitar hacer un recoding de todo lo que tengo funcionando, es decir, quiero que el método b sea de la clase "SmallClass" iniciada dentro de "BigClass", pero que pueda seguir llamándolo como $BigClass->b();

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Qué tal un [encadenador de clases](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/82552/29967)? (ver comentarios)

Answer (score 3):

Es bastante raro lo que quieres hacer... Pero esto te puede funcionar

```
class BigClass{
    private $SmallClass;

    function __construct(){
        $this->SmallClass = new SmallClass();
    }

    public function a(){
        return 'algo';
    }

    public function b(){
        return $this->SmallClass->b();
    }
}

class SmallClass{
    public function b(){
        return "nada";
    }
}

$BigClass = new BigClass();
$BigClass->SmallClass->b() // retorna "nada"
$BigClass->b() // retorna "nada"
```

y esto, tambien te puede funcionar

> extendiendo de la clase ya tienes todos los métodos de la clase que se extiende

```
class BigClass extends SmallClass{
    private $SmallClass;

    function __construct(){
        $this->SmallClass = $this
    }

    public function a(){
        return 'algo';
    }
}

class SmallClass{
    public function b(){
        return "nada";
    }
}

$BigClass = new BigClass();
$BigClass->SmallClass->b() // retorna "nada"
$BigClass->b() // retorna "nada"
```

Comment: Ten en cuenta el apunte de OP en el que se `requiere` que SmallClass se inicie dentro de BigClass (@skeptic cuidado con el [acoplamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoplamiento_inform%C3%A1tico)!!)  Con esa premisa, tu segunda opción parece no válida.

Comment: Pero fue una posible solución, el ni siquiera especificó para que lo necesitaba, de repente a medida que valla desarrollando puede cambiar la lógica.

Comment: Tengo una clase enorme, con unos 100 métodos y 60 objetos, programada durante unos 7 años. Estamos rompiendo la clase en trozos más pequeños, por ejemplo, para algunos proyectos no necesitamos control de sesiones, o gestión de usuarios, por poner un ejemplo.

Answer (score 2):

lo que estas tratando de hacer se puede resolver de esta manera usando un patron de diseño llamado factory

```
class A {
   public function metodoA(){  
       return 'metodo A';
   }
}

class B {
    public function metodoB(){  
        return 'metodo B';
    }
}

class Factory(){
    public function metodoC(){  
        $intanciaA= new MetodoA(); 
        $intanciaB= new MetodoB();
        return $instanciaA->metodoA().' '.$instanciaB->metodoB();
    }
}

$factory=new Factory();
echo $factory->metodoC();

//imprime metodo A metodoB
```

Answer (score 2):

Te propongo usar el método mágico [`__call`](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call)

```
<?php
class BigClass{

    public function __construct(){
        $this->SmallClass = new SmallClass();
    }

    public function a(){
        return "algo";
    }

    public function __call($name , $arguments = null){

        if (method_exists($this->SmallClass, $name)) {
            return $this->SmallClass->$name($arguments);
        } else {
            // Esto quiere decir que el método llamado no existe en ninguna
            // de las dos clases, tocaría controlar el error (lanzar 
            // exception, devolver null...)
        }

    }
}

class SmallClass{

    public function b(){
        return "nada";
    }
}
```

Así todo método que no esté definido explícitamente en BigClass, se intentará ejecutar en SmallClass, y si no existe en ninguna, puedes controlar el error. Por otro lado, te ahorras duplicar cada método de SmallClass en BigClass.